# Pivot is not giving result as expected, how to achieve the expected result?

Tags: t-sql

Here is the data from base table.

```
item    yearww  AssyIn  CW_Req  CW_Req_LT   Pipeline_Inventory
H32788  201927  123.02  44.47   279.16      639
H32788  201928  80.26   50.47   62.95       NULL
H32788  201929  228.96  64.19   65.17       NULL
H32788  201930  27.58   61.34   60.42       NULL
```

I am using pivot to transform column to rows, but aggregation is required for pivot, which is not required in expected output.
`WW27, 28, 29, 30` are column headers. And `Assy In, CW Req, TPT, CW Req in LT, Pipeline Inventory` are row labels.

```
+--------------------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|                    |  WW27  |  WW28 |  WW29  |  WW30 |
+--------------------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| Assy In            | 123.02 | 80.26 | 228.96 | 27.58 |
| CW Req             |  44.47 | 50.47 |  64.19 | 61.34 |
| TPT                |      4 |     4 |      4 |     4 |
| CW Req in LT       | 279.16 | 62.95 |  65.17 | 60.42 |
| Pipeline Inventory |    639 |       |        |       |
+--------------------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'MAX' for aggregation - however this will require another 'group by' 
Something like below

```
SELECT  datatype , item , MAX([201927]) , MAX([201928]) , MAX([201929]) , MAX([201930])
FROM    ( SELECT    'assylin' AS datatype ,
                    item ,
                    [201927] ,
                    [201928] ,
                    [201929] ,
                    [201930]
          FROM      ( SELECT    *
                      FROM      #temp
                    ) AS s 
                    PIVOT ( MAX(assylin) FOR yearww IN ( [201927], [201928], [201929], [201930] ) )
 AS p
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    'cw_req' AS datatype ,
                    item ,
                    [201927] ,
                    [201928] ,
                    [201929] ,
                    [201930]
          FROM      ( SELECT    *
                      FROM      #temp
                    ) AS s PIVOT ( MAX(cw_req) FOR yearww IN ( [201927], [201928], [201929], [201930] ) )
 AS p
        ) AS k
GROUP BY k.datatype ,
        k.item;
```